# Angular: ng-model and ng-show not working

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ng-show

I'm trying to use the `ng-show` and `ng-model` directives to toggle a div when a checkbox is selected. I searched for many tutorial and it seems as simple as my following code:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" unchecked name="advanced" ng-model="checked">
    <p>Advanced search</p>
</div>
<p ng-show="checked">
  advanced-search works!
</p>
```

But nothing happens. Am I missing something? Do I have to import something specific inside my `AppModule`?
Thanks for any hint.

**Comment to the solution**
I'm using `Angular 4` as specified after being asked. I'm new to Angular so I didn't get that the `ng-show` and `ng-model` are not used anymore. The documentation is not always clear and these two directives are used in almost every tutorial, so I thought there was a matter of choiche which one to use.
The selected answer was the working one, but a thanks goes to everyone who pointed out that those directives were wrong for my Angular version.

Comment: Are you using angularjs or angular?

Comment: which version of angular you are using?  Angular2/4 dont have ng-show or ng-model.

Comment: for ng-model change tag to angularjs instead of angular

Comment: @Faisal I'm using Angular4. How should it be done?

Comment: @Deepa the code is not working, that's why the question is posted here! Wait until we get more information

Comment: @Deepa OP is using angular 4

Comment: @esseara that ain't Angular 4 syntax. It's `hidden` and `ngModel`.

Comment: @esseara see my answer

Comment: Are you sure that you are using angular 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-show and ng-model are part of angularjs (1.x). In angular 4, you can do the following:

> ```
> <div>
>   <input type="checkbox" unchecked name="advanced" [(ngModel)]="checked">
>     <p>Advanced search</p>
> </div>
> <p [hidden]="!checked">
>   advanced-search works!
> </p>
> ```

p.s. the user cleared in his comment on the question that he is using angular4.

Comment: If he asking about angular4 with ng-show and ng-model, where are these keywords in your question which is upvoted?

Comment: dear @slacker ng-show and ng-model are not available in angular4! My answer is upvoted because it is correct according to angular4 :) Please read some documentation and stay up to date (Y)

Comment: The question which you answered that's not written in angular 4 for your kind info. User asked question with some version and posted some other version. Is this way to question and before providing answer you should get clear info. People reads question and each and every comment. Next time onwards, please answer in java if someone by mistake asked question in JS. Wastage of time for such a silly question.

Comment: How this can help if he's not using angular 4 ?..I could answer using react.js according to react.js is working... does it help ? not ..so ?

Answer (score -1):

I just copy paste your code and it's working fine... the only thing that has different it's the `ng-app` in the body

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="">

<div>
  <input type="checkbox"  name="advanced" ng-model="checked">
    <p>Advanced search</p>
</div>
<p ng-show="checked">
  advanced-search works!
</p>



</body>
```

Comment: OP is using Angular 4. This is AngularJS.

Comment: ng-show angular 4 ?????? ....angular 4 we bind model like this [(ngModel)]